# Small side trips traveling between US & India

Tags: usa, india, destinations, stopovers

When traveling from US to India, I know that its very easy to have a short tourist stop in

- Singapore: Stopovers >3hrs(?) get a free tour of the city
- Hong Kong: Visa on arrival, on an 8hr stopover I could get a visa and sightsee

As an Indian citizen with US Green Card (permanent residency), which other tourist destinations can be considered for such a trip, by perhaps going for slightly longer stopover and a specific airline to visit a city at minimal extra cost?

I'm looking for options that

- don't require visa or allow visa on arrival (no advance planning needed)
- easy for a tourist to sightsee (availability of guided tours, or safe to roam the city)
- since its for small stopovers, excepting visa & local tourism cost it should be minimal added expense
- given above point, I'd expect such locations would probably be a hub for airlines flying US->India, or close to one?

Places such as UAE that need a little preparation afaik (invitation by residents or hotel booking) can also be mentioned as it would help others.

Comment: You can have a stopover at practically any place with a visa for that place while going from India to US. So what's your criteria to limit that?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: Edited the question to explain further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the available flights, you have two options:

1. Flying east you could stop in Europe, common stop-overs are London, Paris, Amsterdam, Frankfurt, Vienna, or all the way to Dubai.
2. When flying west in addition to Singapore and Hong Kong other options are: Seoul, Bangkok, Tokyo or Shanghai.

All these cities are interesting enough for a few days or more (I haven't been to Seoul, so I can't judge it).

Next check 'Visa'. Which of these countries can you visit without an advanced visa. Of course this depends on your nationality. I assume you have an Indian passport. I don't think a US Green Card helps.

A good source for the question 'Do I need a visa' is [VisaHQ](http://www.visahq.com/citizens/India/)

It rules out all the European cities, also the Emirates. Of all the Asian stop-overs only Hong Kong is listed as visa free.

You can visit many Island states in the Caribbean and Pacific but none of these 'free' countries are really helpful as a stop-over.

So Hong Kong it is!